# How to add retrofit library with proguardFiles minifyEnabled true in android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-proguard

I am building an android application and I have enable proguard as true.

What I am facing the problem is when I add retrofit library and generate the APK to release mode it display errors and my APK is not build.

Could some one help me in solving this issue How to use retrofit library with proguard as true.

Comment: show your error's screenshot

Comment: @pcpriyanka this is the error : "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have coded a project test with *retrofit2*. When i generate signed apk with proguard, some error occured. I have tried remove all warning display in **message window** with this code:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
```

Then i can generate apk without error.

Comment: can you please explain in brief how it will help me

Comment: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit.**' not working

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: @hiteshmatnani insert two line code in **proguard-rules.pro** file, but not _build.gradle#dependencies_